# JQueryMobile with JSF 2.0 not rendering on Android browser

Tags: android, jsf-2, jquery-mobile

I have a jQueryMobile application with JSF 2.0. (JBoss 7)

The issue is: index.jsf returns html containing jQM List which does not render on **Android** (Just plain links instead of the nice jQM list). This works as expected in other browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc.

*The strange thing is if I save the same html output (returned by index.jsf) as index.html and access html file, it works as expected.*

Puzzled and frustrated why the **same html** will work when served as html file but NOT when served as jsf page.

index.jsf response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: JSF/2.0
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=5ZLbSNpM3cumhlXupMMFEbiE; Path=/itranzit
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2011 12:03:13 GMT
```

index.html response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: W/"2905-1323086637000"-gzip
Last-Modified: Mon, 05 Dec 2011 12:03:57 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2011 12:04:00 GMT
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks heaps!